# How can i integrate MATLAB with Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, matlab, oslc

I am new to the topic of OSLC integration.
I have few questions in my mind.

1. How to know that tools supports OSLC or not.
2. Can i integrate MATLAB with Eclipse?

Answer (score 2):

### Give MATCLIPSE a try:

Eclipse has a MATLAB plugin available

**Installation**
How to install matclipse:

**Update site**

Add http://matclipse.eclipselabs.org.codespot.com/git.update/ to the update sites in Help -> Install New Software and install Matclipse. For Windows systems, you need to install the win32 extras too.

**IMPORTANT** (Linux/MacOS): The MATLAB path is not set at the first start, you need to set it in `Window`->`Preferences`

**From source**

The plugins are available in the Git repository: https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/matclipse/source/checkout

To build the plugin yourself in Eclipse, you need the Eclipse, the PDE and the EGit plugin, which is available in the update manager. (The Eclipse Classic SDK includes PDE). Then you need to do the following steps:

1) Open perspective "Git Repository Exploring" and pull the repository from the URL https://code.google.com/a/eclipselabs.org/p/matclipse/

2) Open the Java perspective, right click one plugin and click "Run as Eclipse Application"

To run matclipse on win32, you need com.jacob, which is also included in the source repository. This plugin is not necessary on other systems.

You should get a new Eclipse instance with the matclipse plugin running inside.

**IMPORTANT** (Linux/MacOS): The MATLAB path is not set at the first start, you need to set it in `Window`->`Preferences`

You can then switch to the MATLAB Workbench perspective and start working!

For instructions how to include a plugin into the running Eclipse environment, see http://www.vogella.de/articles/EclipsePlugIn/article.html#deployplugin

Answer (score 2):

### 1. OSLC supporting tools

As of today, there are only a few tools that support OSLC out-of-the-box. You a probably find out by checking their product page (or search the source code if available).

However, there are several initiatives that provide OSLC libraries, which you can use to integrate any tool with proper APIs. One such is the [Eclipse Lyo](https://www.eclipse.org/lyo/) platform. Another example is Rational Jazz.

Eclipse Lyo also has a small example for an OSLC Simulink adapter (Eclipse wiki/Lyo/Simulink).

### 2. Integrating MATLAB and Eclipse

Take a look at [Massif](https://github.com/FTSRG/massif), which sounds like what you need.

It provides a simple command evaluation API (massif/wiki/ApiUsageExample) for Matlab from Eclipse with added support for importing MATLAB Simulink models to EMF and exporting from EMF to Simulink.

Finally, it includes an OSLC-based Simulink model explorer (massif/wiki/OSLCAdaptorGuide) that uses the API to connect to MATLAB and provide Simulink models as OSLC resources. This integration was built using Eclipse Lyo.