# How do I set up com.mathworks.engine in Eclipse?

Tags: java, matlab

For some reason I am unable to `import com.mathworks.engine.*` using the following line:

```
import com.mathworks.engine.*;
```

I have Matlab 2019b installed as well as Eclipse. I couldn't find much online on how exactly to set up the MATLAB Engine API for Java. Can anyone advise on how I can get this set up correctly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i integrate MATLAB with Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26584329/how-can-i-integrate-matlab-with-eclipse)