# how to use Matlab in eclipse IDE?

Tags: eclipse, matlab, xtext

i am working on a project with eclipse IDE . I want to use Matlab on eclipse IDE (to import a matlab file and use it on Eclipse).
All Solution that i found on internet are for Eclipse SDK but i need to work with IDE.
can you please help me ?
thank you a lot

Comment: Eclipse SDK is just the name given to the core parts of Eclipse. Most Eclipse IDE downloads include it.

Comment: Perhaps this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/26584917/3222340